# Loop should stop then response body return

Tags: javascript

I have an email list then I will get the email id to request the body email. How to stop the loop to return the response body? Thank you for your help.

```
if (emailBodyContent == undefined || emailBodyContent == '') {
console.log('emailBodyContent: ' + emailBodyContent);
// emailList.forEach((email) => {
for (i = 0; i < emailList.length; i++) {
    console.log('email: ' + emailList[i].mail_subject);
    console.log('subject: ' + subject);
    if (emailList[i].mail_subject == subject) {
        emailId = emailList[i].mail_id;
        console.log('Setting email id: ' + emailList[i].mail_id);
        // Stop the loop once the email is found
        break;
    }
}
// Check if at least one email with the subject and content was found
expect(emailId, 'No email has arrived...').to.not.be.undefined;
expect(emailId, 'Email ID did not return a string').to.be.a('string');
expect(emailId.length).to.be.above(0);

//open email to read content
return cy
    .request(`${apiUrl}f=fetch_email&sid_token=${result.token}&email_id=${emailId}`)
    .then((expectedEmail) => {
        expectedEmail = expectedEmail.body;
        console.log('expectedEmail');
        console.log(expectedEmail);
        emailContent.push({
            id: expectedEmail.mail_id,
            subject: expectedEmail.mail_subject,
            body: JSON.stringify(expectedEmail.mail_body),
            preheader: JSON.stringify(expectedEmail.mail_excerpt)
        });
        return emailContent;
    });
```

}

Comment: You can simply `return cy.request...` in place the `break`

Comment: @Guichi can't be after return, should be in the last statement.

Comment: Your requirement is  **How to stop the loop to return the response body?** and **should be in the last statement**. I got confused, what is wrong with your current solution and what is your real requirement?

Comment: Hi @Guichi this is resolved. Thank you so much for your response.

Answer (score -1):

1. Ensure that `i` is correctly initialized within the loop. If it's not declared elsewhere in your code, you should declare it within the loop.
   `for (let i = 0; i < emailList.length; i++) {`
2. If you want to immediately return the content of an email once its subject matches your target subject, you can simplify your loop's logic by removing the `break` and directly returning the result of your `cy.request`.

```
if (emailBodyContent == undefined || emailBodyContent == '') {
    console.log('emailBodyContent: ' + emailBodyContent);

    for (let i = 0; i < emailList.length; i++) { // Initialized 'i' here
        console.log('email: ' + emailList[i].mail_subject);
        console.log('subject: ' + subject);
        
        if (emailList[i].mail_subject == subject) {
            emailId = emailList[i].mail_id;
            console.log('Setting email id: ' + emailList[i].mail_id);
            
            // Validate the emailId
            expect(emailId, 'No email has arrived...').to.not.be.undefined;
            expect(emailId, 'Email ID did not return a string').to.be.a('string');
            expect(emailId.length).to.be.above(0);

            // Fetch and return the email content upon finding a match
            return cy
                .request(`${apiUrl}f=fetch_email&sid_token=${result.token}&email_id=${emailId}`)
                .then((expectedEmail) => {
                    expectedEmail = expectedEmail.body;
                    console.log('expectedEmail');
                    console.log(expectedEmail);
                    emailContent.push({
                        id: expectedEmail.mail_id,
                        subject: expectedEmail.mail_subject,
                        body: JSON.stringify(expectedEmail.mail_body),
                        preheader: JSON.stringify(expectedEmail.mail_excerpt)
                    });
                    return emailContent;
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).